# Equivalences between statements of (seemingly) different order

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy, reverse-math

In Steve Simpson's excellent monograph SOSOA, we find Theorem X.4.4 which contains an equivalence (over RCA$_0^*$) between the following statements:

1. The induction axiom for $\Sigma_1^0$-formulas (with set parameters, of course).
2. For every countable ﬁeld $K$, every polynomial $f(x)$ in $K[x]$ has only
   ﬁnitely many roots in $K$.

Such equivalences seem rare as they involve a first-order statement (with set parameters) and a 'truly' second-order statement.  My question is then as follows:

*Are there more equivalences of this kind, i.e. between first-order statements (with set parameters) and 'truly' second-order ones?*

I also welcome criticism of my premise, i.e. perhaps 2) is deemed not 'truly' second-order by all?  Perhaps there is a philosophy of math angle too/even?

Comment: *Both* 1 and 2 are first-order statements with second-order parameters. In particular, 2 can be written without second-order quantifiers, using only $K$ and its field operations as second-order parameters.

Answer (score 5):

When we say "with set parameters" I take it that what we really mean is something of the form: the axioms of (e.g.) the $\Sigma^0_1$ induction scheme are the *universal closures* of all formulas of the form $$(\varphi(0) \wedge \forall{n}\varphi(n) \rightarrow \varphi(n+1)) \rightarrow \forall{n}\varphi(n),$$ where $\varphi$ is $\Sigma^0_1$ and may contain free number and set variables—in other words, a set of $\Pi^1_1$ statements.

This muddies the waters somewhat, since e.g. statements asserting that some computable linear order is a well-ordering are also $\Pi^1_1$. For example, $\mathrm{WO}(\omega^\omega)$ is equivalent to Hilbert's basis theorem ([Simpson 1988](https://doi.org/10.2307/2274585)). These sorts of statements (perhaps) don't have quite the same 'feeling' as the example Sam gives.

Another philosophical issue relates to the fact that, according to Simpson, induction schemes like $\mathrm{I}\Sigma^0_1$ are *set existence principles*, in virtue of their equivalence to bounded comprehension schemes (remark II.3.11 in *SoSOA*). This is important in light of the view that reverse mathematics is about determining which set existence principles are necessary in order to prove a given theorem. I push back against Simpson's views on induction schemes a bit in [a 2019 paper](https://doi.org/10.1093/philmat/nky010) (see particularly pages 171–172), in the context of a more general inquiry into whether this is a good way of understanding RM.

Other examples in the vein Sam describes, of equivalences of mathematical statements to $\mathrm{I}\Sigma^0_1$ over $\mathsf{RCA}_0^*$ can be found in ([Simpson and Smith 1986](https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-0072(86)90074-6)),([Hatzikiriakou 1989a](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01630810)), and ([Hatzikiriakou 1989b](https://search.proquest.com/openview/96bd6cda7087da162f45cb3ae8d611e5/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750&diss=y)), e.g. that every finitely generated vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a basis; that every torsion-free, finitely generated abelian group is free; the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups; and the theorem that for every countable field $K$, every polynomial $f(x) \in K[x]$ has only finitely many roots in $K$.

Another one, this time over $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ rather than $\mathsf{RCA}_0^*$, is the equivalence of $\mathsf{RT}^1_{<\infty}$ to the $\Sigma^0_2$ bounding scheme ([Hirst 1987](https://search.proquest.com/openview/bdbd542a8e79f1b38174e0d1863cb8fb/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750&diss=y)). There has been a lot of recent work on the first-order strength of (weakenings of) Ramsey's theorem, both over $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ and $\mathsf{RCA}_0^*$, for example [Kołodziejczyk and Yokoyama (2021)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-80049-9_27).